# Horizontal pan gesture inside UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, swipe

i have a UIcollectionView with vertical scrollView, each row contains a UIView, inside a uiview i have attached a pan gesture in this way:

```
let swipe = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
cell.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

this is the method:

```
func swipe(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = sender.velocityInView(sender.view!)
        switch sender.state {
        case .Ended:
            if point.x < 0 {
                selectedMessageForDetails = sender.message!
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("newView", sender: nil)
            }
        default:break
        }
}
```

All works fine, but in this way when i swipe horizontal in cell, swipe method is called, but if i swipe vertical, the scroll view does not work, how can i solve this?

I would like to have the same aspect of whatsapp message, if i swipe right to left in a bubble i can open a message details, but if i swipe vertical i can scroll the scroll view!

Any ideas?

Comment: you can add swipe to self.view no need to add for each and every view

Comment: And how can i identify the current cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can give Gesture to self .view not to individual cell

```
    let swipe = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipe:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

to identify the current cell you can use in action  method

```
let point = swipe .locationInView(self.view)

let indexPath = collectionview.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)
```